# how do we handle refresh token from the client's side in JWT?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, angular, express, jwt

I'd like to know what happens exactly in the client side when the refresh token expires.

1. Does the user get redirected to a login page and stay logged in, or does the client side automatically log him out?

As far as I understood, the refresh token is stored in an HTTP-only cookie, but the access token is stored in local storage. I noticed that when restarting the computer, the cookie is cleared, but the local storage remains. Wouldn't that create access problems?
Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Access Token is not stored in local storage, it is stored as a state. After logging in, if you leave the site and come back later, obviously the access token is gone, so, your client should check if there's a valid refresh token present as a cookie. If yes, your backend sends a fresh access token which you again store in your state, not in local storage.

Comment: thank you for your response brother, i have another question, how to ensure that when the user closes the tab he doesn't get logged out since the auth-state becomes null, or am i missing something ?

Comment: that's why we save a cookie in the browser. the cookie is nothing but the refresh token. even if user closes the tab, the cookie will be there for your site in the browser. so next time when user opens the site, it accesses the cookie, sends a request to the backend asking for a new accesstoken. 

i would suggest you go through Dave Gray's react tutorial for access and refresh token, and role based access on youtube, it will clear all your doubts.